# Converting yyyy numeric data to date format in R

Tags: r, date-conversion

I have a dataset, `df` with a column containing dates in yyyy format (ex: 2018). I’m trying to make a time series graph, and therefore need to convert them to a date format.

I initially tried, `df$year <- as.Date(df$year)` but was told I needed to specify an origin.

I then tried to convert to a character, then a date format: 
`df$year <- as.character(df$year)
df$year <- as.Date(df$year, format = “%Y”)`

This seems to have worked, however when it changed the all the years to yyyy-mm-dd format, and set the month and day to April 5th, today. For example 2018 becomes 2018-04-05.

Does anyone have an idea for how to fix this? I would like it to start on January 1, not the day I am performing the conversion. I also tried `strptime(as.character(beer_states$year), “%Y”)` with the same result.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an arbitrary date and month before converting to date.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(paste(df$year, 1, 1), '%Y %m %d')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.yearmon`

```
library(zoo)
df$Date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(df$year, '-01'), '%Y-%m'))
```